# Sharing .hg/hgrc settings across all clones

Tags: mercurial, hgrc

Is there any way to easily share `.hg/hgrc` settings across all clones of a Mercurial repo?

e.g., I want to automatically enable the [commitsigs extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/CommitsigsExtension) for all clones of a repo (obviously, I'd include a copy of `commitsigs.py` in the repo).  If I make other settings changes over time, I want them all to be easily pushed out to all clones.

I want to have:

1. `hg clone` automatically setup the `.hg/hgrc` of a new clone
2. all clones receive updated settings from the central repo (presumably on bitbucket.com)

If there is no built-in functionality for this, is the best practice to:

1. have a `mandatory.hgrc` in the root of the repo
2. use the ACL extension to restrict committers & pushers for `mandatory.hgrc`
3. have scripts in the root of the repo named something like `setup-hg.sh` & `setup-hg.bat` (are there better, more standard names?) that add the following to `.hg/hgrc` (or that overwrite `.hg/hgrc`):

   ```
   %include ../mandatory.hgrc
   ```
4. include a `README.md` containing instructions to run `setup-hg.sh` or `setup-hg.bat`, depending on your platform

Comment: This might be helpful https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConfigExpressExtension

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I’ll look into it soon. As per my reply to your comment on my other question: is there any way to do this on a bitbucket.com repo?

Comment: sorry again, I don't think this can be done on bitbucket.

Comment: Provide a readme to explain how to setup the extension, and use the server-side hook to ensure commits pushed to your repository have valid signatures.